# Updating/Refreshing python Tkinter Frames

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am currently working on a little project regarding a financial app calculating payrolls. I successfully create multiple pages using tkinter widget in pyCharm. After successfully designing the main few pages, and getting the code to run and execute, I ran into a problem where my pages, or frames, are static and do not refresh. 
Case example: I would click on "Add Employee", which will open the adding frame, and fill up the three input pages. After I submit, my database is being updated with an Insert, the program checks if such Employee exists, and the function executes accordingly. However, my main page list box which displays all of the employees from the DB will not update with the new employee upon return to the frame. I've been looking online, and can't seem to find a solution to this problem, as update() did not work for me so far, unless I used it absolutely wrong.

I could really use some help, and would appreciate some guidance on this.

How would I refresh my Main page, and any page in that matter, because the input in the entry boxes does not seem to go away from the registration frames either (When i navigate back to them again)

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk  # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont, Entry, END  # python 3
# import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
# import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2
from tkinter import messagebox
import Employee
import pymysql.cursors
from pymysql.connections import Connection


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args)
        self.shared_data = {
            "first_name": tk.StringVar(),
            "last_name": tk.StringVar(),
            "age": tk.StringVar(),
            "address": tk.StringVar(),
            "day_of_birth": tk.StringVar(),
            "month_of_birth": tk.StringVar(),
            "year_of_birth": tk.StringVar(),
            "health_care": tk.StringVar(),
            "health_care_id": tk.StringVar(),
            "employee_id": tk.StringVar(),
            "married": tk.StringVar(),
            "hInsurance": tk.StringVar(),
            "dInsurance": tk.StringVar(),
            "oInsurance": tk.StringVar(),
            "hTier": tk.StringVar(),
            "four01k": tk.StringVar(),
            "kContribution": tk.StringVar(),
            "pension": tk.StringVar(),
            "unionDues": tk.StringVar(),
            "payType": tk.StringVar(),
            "payAmount": tk.StringVar(),
        }

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Payroll Application")

        #Creation of all the relevant Frames

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(200, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(200, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (LoginPage, mainMenuPage, addEmpFrame, addEmpFrame1, addEmpFrame2, removeEmpFrame, EmpLookupFrame,
                  calcPayRollFrame):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.raise_frame(LoginPage)

        #Frame manipulation functions

    def raise_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def update_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.update()

    def destroy_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.destroy()

#Frame Designs
#Each frame  written in a class format

class LoginPage(tk.Frame): #Login page Frame
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label_username = tk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = tk.Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me logged in")
        self.checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.loginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(self.submitLogin()))
        self.loginButton.grid(columnspan=2)

    def submitLogin(self):
        l = self.entry_username.get()
        p = self.entry_password.get()
        attempt = Employee.Login(l, p)
        attempt.databaseSearchId(attempt.get_temp_id())
        if (attempt.check_login() == 1):
            return mainMenuPage
        elif (attempt.check_login() == 0):
            return LoginPage


class mainMenuPage(tk.Frame): #Main Menu Frame, consists of the main navigation page, List box
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller
        self.row = []


        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.scrollbar.grid(row = 2, column= 2)

        connection: Connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                                 port=3306,
                                                 user='root',
                                                 password='root',
                                                 db='hrdb')
        cursorObject = connection.cursor()
        cursorObject.execute('SELECT `firstName`,`lastName` from `employeeprofile`')
        numrows = int(cursorObject.rowcount)
        for x in range(0, numrows):
            self.row.append(cursorObject.fetchone())

        self.list1 = tk.Listbox(self, height=10, width=35)
        for x in self.row:
            self.list1.insert(END, x)
        self.list1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.list1.yview)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Search employee by typing his/her last name:")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=3)


        button = tk.Button(self, text='Add Employee', width=15,
                            command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(addEmpFrame))
        button.grid(row=2, column=3)
        button = tk.Button(self, text='Remove Employee', width=15, command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(removeEmpFrame))
        button.grid(row=3, column=3)
        button = tk.Button(self, text='Employee Lookup', width=15, command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(EmpLookupFrame))
        button.grid(row=4, column=3)
        button = tk.Button(self, text='Calculate Pay Roll', width=15, command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(calcPayRollFrame))
        button.grid(row=5, column=3)






class addEmpFrame(tk.Frame): #One of the three registration Frames, Button NEXT moves to the next registration page
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        empInfoLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Please enter Personal information.')
        empInfoLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

        labelFirstName = tk.Label(self, text="Employee First Name")
        labelFirstName.grid(row=1, column=0)
        labelLastName = tk.Label(self, text="Employee Last Name")
        labelLastName.grid(row=2, column=0)
        labelAge = tk.Label(self, text="Employee Age")
        labelAge.grid(row=3, column=0)
        labelAddress = tk.Label(self, text="Employee full address?(street, city, state, zip")
        labelAddress.grid(row=4, column=0)
        labelDOB = tk.Label(self, text="Employee day of birth")
        labelDOB.grid(row=5, column=0)
        labelMOB = tk.Label(self, text="Employee month of birth")
        labelMOB.grid(row=6, column=0)
        labelYOB = tk.Label(self, text="Employee year of birth")
        labelYOB.grid(row=7, column=0)
        labelHealthCare = tk.Label(self, text="Health Care (yes or no)")
        labelHealthCare.grid(row=8, column=0)
        labelHealthCareID = tk.Label(self, text="Employee health care id")
        labelHealthCareID.grid(row=9, column=0)
        labelEmployeeID = tk.Label(self, text="Employee id")
        labelEmployeeID.grid(row=10, column=0)

        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["first_name"])
        userEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["last_name"])
        userEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["age"])
        userEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["address"])
        userEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["day_of_birth"])
        userEntry.grid(row=5, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["month_of_birth"])
        userEntry.grid(row=6, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["year_of_birth"])
        userEntry.grid(row=7, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["health_care"])
        userEntry.grid(row=8, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["health_care_id"])
        userEntry.grid(row=9, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["employee_id"])
        userEntry.grid(row=10, column=1)

        nextButton = tk.Button(self, text='Next', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(addEmpFrame1))
        nextButton.grid(row=12, column=1)

        retButton = tk.Button(self, text='Main Menu', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(mainMenuPage))
        retButton.grid(row=12, column=0)


class addEmpFrame1(tk.Frame): #second registration page, button NEXT moves to the next registration page
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        empInfo2Label = tk.Label(self, text='Please enter Insurance information.')
        empInfo2Label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        labelMarried = tk.Label(self, text="Married? (yes or no)")
        labelMarried.grid(row=1, column=0)
        labelhInsurance = tk.Label(self, text="Health Care Insurance company")
        labelhInsurance.grid(row=2, column=0)
        labeldInsurance = tk.Label(self, text="Dental Care Insurance company")
        labeldInsurance.grid(row=3, column=0)
        labeloInsurance = tk.Label(self, text="Optical Care Insurance company")
        labeloInsurance.grid(row=4, column=0)
        labelhTier = tk.Label(self, text="hTier")
        labelhTier.grid(row=5, column=0)

        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["married"])
        userEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["hInsurance"])
        userEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["dInsurance"])
        userEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["oInsurance"])
        userEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["hTier"])
        userEntry.grid(row=5, column=1)

        nextButton = tk.Button(self, text='Next', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(addEmpFrame2))
        nextButton.grid(row=7, column=1)

        retButton = tk.Button(self, text='Main Menu', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(mainMenuPage))
        retButton.grid(row=7, column=0)


class addEmpFrame2(tk.Frame): #Final registration page, SUBMIT checks if exists in db, if not, Inserts
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        empInfo3Label = tk.Label(self, text='Please enter Financial information.')
        empInfo3Label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        label401k = tk.Label(self, text="401k (yes or no)")
        label401k.grid(row=1, column=0)
        labelkContribution = tk.Label(self, text="kContribution")
        labelkContribution.grid(row=2, column=0)
        labelPension = tk.Label(self, text="Pension (yes or no)")
        labelPension.grid(row=3, column=0)
        labelUnionDues = tk.Label(self, text="Union dues (yes or no)")
        labelUnionDues.grid(row=4, column=0)
        labelPayType = tk.Label(self, text="Pay type")
        labelPayType.grid(row=5, column=0)
        labelPayAmount = tk.Label(self, text="Pay amount")
        labelPayAmount.grid(row=6, column=0)

        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["four01k"])
        userEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["kContribution"])
        userEntry.grid(row=2, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["pension"])
        userEntry.grid(row=3, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["unionDues"])
        userEntry.grid(row=4, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["payType"])
        userEntry.grid(row=5, column=1)
        userEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["payAmount"])
        userEntry.grid(row=6, column=1)

        submitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=lambda: self.addEmployee(controller))
        submitButton.grid(row=8, column=1)

        retButton = tk.Button(self, text='Main Menu', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(mainMenuPage))
        retButton.grid(row=8, column=0)

    def addEmployee(self, controller): #Checking and inserting function

        temp_stat = 0

        firstName = self.controller.shared_data["first_name"].get()
        lastName = self.controller.shared_data["last_name"].get()
        aGe = self.controller.shared_data["age"].get()
        addRess = self.controller.shared_data["address"].get()
        DOB = self.controller.shared_data["day_of_birth"].get()
        MOB = self.controller.shared_data["month_of_birth"].get()
        YOB = self.controller.shared_data["year_of_birth"].get()
        healthCare = self.controller.shared_data["health_care"].get()
        healthCareID = self.controller.shared_data["health_care_id"].get()
        employeeID = self.controller.shared_data["employee_id"].get()
        marry = self.controller.shared_data["married"].get()
        healthIns = self.controller.shared_data["hInsurance"].get()
        dentalIns = self.controller.shared_data["dInsurance"].get()
        opticalIns = self.controller.shared_data["oInsurance"].get()
        healthTier = self.controller.shared_data["hTier"].get()
        Four1k = self.controller.shared_data["four01k"].get()
        keyContribution = self.controller.shared_data["kContribution"].get()
        penSion = self.controller.shared_data["pension"].get()
        unionDues = self.controller.shared_data["unionDues"].get()
        payType = self.controller.shared_data["payType"].get()
        payAmount = self.controller.shared_data["payAmount"].get()

        attempt = Employee.Register(firstName, lastName, aGe, addRess, DOB, MOB, YOB,
                                    healthCare, healthCareID, employeeID, marry, healthIns,
                                    dentalIns, opticalIns, healthTier, Four1k, keyContribution,
                                    penSion, unionDues, payType, payAmount)
        temp_stat = attempt.databaseInsert()

        if(temp_stat == 1):
            messagebox.showinfo("Status", "Successfully Added")
            controller.raise_frame(mainMenuPage)
            controller.update_frame(mainMenuPage)

        elif(temp_stat == 0):
            messagebox.showinfo("Status", "User Already Exists")
            controller.raise_frame(addEmpFrame)


class removeEmpFrame(tk.Frame): #Under construction
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        retButton = tk.Button(self, text='Main Menu', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(mainMenuPage))
        retButton.grid(row=12, column=0)


class EmpLookupFrame(tk.Frame): #Under Construction
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        retButton = tk.Button(self, text='Main Menu', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(mainMenuPage))
        retButton.grid(row=12, column=0)


class calcPayRollFrame(tk.Frame): #Under construction
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        retButton = tk.Button(self, text='Main Menu', command=lambda: controller.raise_frame(mainMenuPage))
        retButton.grid(row=12, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui = GUI()
    gui.mainloop()
```

EDIT: I am aware the bulk code is long to read, However I don't really have a specific location for the problem, rather, if you take a look at any class of any Frame, what am I missing logically to get the frames to update/refresh upon using them. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When asking about a specific problem you need to provide a small example that can reproduce the issue. Posting a wall of text is not helpful and will result in downvotes and can lead to not getting an answer. As a side note please edit your imports. All you need is `import tkinter as tk` and `from tkinter import messagebox`. The rest is not needed as far as tkinter is concerned.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll try to see how can I ask this in a shorter way. I am aware it is a large bulk of code, but I am not sure which part may specifically represent the problem, rather, the class design I have for each class may be missing something. That was the reason for my annoyingly long code for a question... and you are right, I was trying different things with imports and never removed them, thank you, removed them

Comment: You need to clear your entry fields each time your page is raised. The problem is mainly because your page gets built once and then only moved around after that.

Comment: You should run a function that clears each string var from the dictionary.

Comment: That makes sense, yes. Would that be the same approach to my list box? in Main Menu page, I have the list box which reads info from the Database and displays it in a table. The only way will be running it as a method every time the frame is raised?

Comment: You would have to build a method that is called when frame is raised and that method would just iterate over the dictionary and reset each stringvar. Should be relatively simple to set up.

Comment: I'll look it up and get into clearing the dictionary right away, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to clear the dictionary values each time you click the add new employee button.

One way to do this is to add a method to the GUI class that has a for loop to set all values to an empty string.

Then you would simply call that method before you lift the frame by adding it to your lambda statement.

So add this method to the GUI class.

```
def clear_shared_data(self):
    for key, value in self.shared_data.items():
        print(value.get())
        value.set("")
```

Then edit your `'Add Employee'` button to have the following command.

```
command=lambda: (controller.clear_shared_data(), controller.raise_frame(addEmpFrame))
```

This will clear your values in your dictionary just before you raise frame.

Comment: Thank you, you made my life much easier right now. I will apply the same principle with the second issue. For some reason, before, I failed to run two methods with the command line so I assumed it works for a single function. That is very helpful